# ElasticSearch Snapshot Creation - understanding how/where to store them to

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a Linux-based ElasticSearch 6.4 cluster with 4 indexes which we are running in the Azure cloud on Linux VM's.  I am reading the documentation about creating snapshots of indexes but getting a little stumped on the storage of the snapshot.

We want to create and store daily snapshots off of the VM that runs the cluster, so that if the VM fails, those snapshots are still available to us for restoration once we get the VM back up and running.

So what I am looking for guidance on is an API call query I can run to create a snapshot of an index (let's say the index is called "index01") which I can store somewhere in Azure storage.

Is this possible?  Is the default behavior to just store the snapshot on the same disk as where the index resides?  If so, I'm not sure I would understand this as if disk or VM corruption occurs, you lose the snapshots as well.

Any guidance or recommendations would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. It doesn't make much sense to store your snapshots on the same disks/hosts where you're running ES. The whole purpose of snapshots is to act as a backup in case something bad happens and you need to rebuild your cluster.

Luckily for you, there is indeed a repository plugin for [Azure storage](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/6.5/repository-azure.html). After [installing the plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/6.5/repository-azure.html) on all nodes and restarting them, you can create your repository like this:

```
PUT _snapshot/azure_backup
{
    "type": "azure",
    "settings": {
        "container": "backup-container",
        "base_path": "backups",
        "chunk_size": "32m",
        "compress": true
    }
}
```

When done, you can easily [create your snapshots](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html#_snapshot) like this:

```
PUT /_snapshot/azure_backup/snapshot_1
{
  "indices": "index01",
  "ignore_unavailable": true,
  "include_global_state": true
}
```

Comment: Hi Val! Your ElasticSearch help around here is invaluable, thanks so much!  I will investigate this now and mark this as the answer as soon as possible.  Thanks again!

Comment: Val, I know with a lot of ES plugins, the version number of the plugin must be the exact same version as the ElasticSearch instance.  Do you know if this is the case for this plugin you have referenced?  If so, do you know where I can get version 6.4.2, which is the version of ElasticSearch we are currently on?

Comment: Always glad to help out! You're absolutely correct, the version should match. In your case you should try an [offline install](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/6.5/plugin-management-custom-url.html#plugin-management-custom-url) using the following artifact: https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch-plugins/repository-azure/repository-azure-6.4.2.zip

Comment: Hi Val,  Yes, all seems to be working well!  I have marked your answer.  Thanks again!